# websocket readyState 0 (CONNECTING)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, websocket

I'm trying to implement a simple web socket application.

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

class SocketService {
  async connectService() {
    try {
      this.socket = await new WebSocket("wss://localhost:3000/", {
        origin: "https://localhost:3000",
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      });
      return this.socket;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      process.exit(0);
    }
  }

  async sendMessage() {
    try {
      await this.socket.send("test 123");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      process.exit(0);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new SocketService();
```

```
"use strict";

// Create an instance of a ws client
const socketService = require("./wss_client");

// Connect websocket
(async () => {
  try {
    // connectService works
    await socketService.connectService();
   // sendMessage doesn't work
    await socketService.sendMessage();    
    });

  } catch (err) {
    // err
  }
})();
```

But when calling socketService.sendMessage() I get this erorr.

> Error: WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. As always thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try a callBack method:

```
private async connectToWs(callback) {
    try {
        this.websocket = await new WebSocket(WIDGET_URL as string);
        this.websocket.onopen = callback;
        this.websocket.onerror = console.error;
        return this.websocket
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
    }
}
```

"onopen" callback will tigger a send:

```
await this.connectToWs(async () => await this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(Entries)));
```